# How to interact with plot using keyboard arros?

Tags: plot, julia, slider, interaction, makie.jl

My interactive plot (topoplot) reacts to mouse signals, but how to make it reacting to keyboard signals?

Here is my code:

```
f = Figure()
xs = 1:1:193 #range(-30, 120, length = size(dat_e, 2))
sg = SliderGrid(f[2, 1],
(label="time", range=xs, format = "{:d} ms", startvalue = 100),
)
time = sg.sliders[1].value
str = lift(t -> "[$t ms]", time)
topo_slice = lift((t, data) -> mean(data[1:30, t, :], dims=2)[:,1], time, dat_e)
topo_axis = Axis(f[1, 1], aspect = DataAspect())
topo = eeg_topoplot!(topo_axis, topo_slice, 
    raw.ch_names[1:30]; 
    positions=pos, # produced  automatically from ch_names
    label_text=true) # aspect ratio, correlation of height and width

text!(topo_axis, 1, 1, text = str,  align = (:center, :center))
#topo_slice = lift((t, data) -> data[:, :, t], time, topo)

xlims!(-0.2, 1.1)
ylims!(-0.2, 1.2)
hidedecorations!(topo_axis)
hidespines!(topo_axis) 
f
```

There is an official instruction https://docs.juliahub.com/AbstractPlotting/6fydZ/0.12.11/interaction.html, but as usual with Julia documentations, there is no example and I have no idea how implement it in my code.

How my plot looks like:
[image]

Comment: What do you want the keys to do?

Comment: just to make a step forward or backward on the slider. It is hard to do that using a mouse.

Comment: AbstractPlotting.ispressed() will tell you if a key is pressed.  See Makie docs for keyboardbuttons::Observable{Set{AbstractPlotting.Keyboard.Button}} also. You will need to change the slider based on the input manually -- see for example AbstractPlotting.MakieLayout.set_close_to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the answer from before:

```
T = 10

pts = range(-1, 1, length=100)
ts = reshape(1:T, 1, 1, :)
topo = cos.(pts) .+ cos.(ts .* pts')

fig = Figure()
ax = Axis(fig[1, 1])

sg = SliderGrid(fig[2,1],
    (label="time", range=1:T))

time = sg.sliders[1].value

str = lift(t -> "[$t ms]", time)
text!(ax, str)

topo_slice = lift((t, data) -> data[:, :, t], time, topo)

# decrement/increment slider with left/right keys
on(events(fig).keyboardbutton) do btn
    if btn.action in (Keyboard.press, Keyboard.repeat)
        if btn.key == Keyboard.left
            set_close_to!(sg.sliders[1], time[] - 1)
        elseif btn.key == Keyboard.right
            set_close_to!(sg.sliders[1], time[] + 1)
        end
    end
end

contour!(ax, topo_slice)

hidedecorations!(ax)
hidespines!(ax) 
fig
```